# Ant compile error while using analytics jar file

Tags: android, ant

I'm trying to compile my android project with and I can't seem to get passed this error:

> -dex:
>        [echo]
>        [echo]         Converting compiled files and external libraries
>   into K:\bin \classes.dex...
>        [echo]
>       [apply]
>       [apply] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       [apply] com.android.dx.util.ExceptionWithContext
>       [apply]     at com.android.dx.util.ExceptionWithContext.withContext(Exceptio
>   nWithContext.java:46)
>       [apply]     at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslato
>   r.java:340)
>       [apply]     at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.ja
>   va:131)
>       [apply]     at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.jav
>   a:85)
>       [apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:336)
>
> ```
> [apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:
> ```
>
> 315)
>       [apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$100(Main.java:56)
>       [apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.jav
>   a:266)
>       [apply]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(Class
>   PathOpener.java:244)
>       [apply]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPath
>   Opener.java:130)
>       [apply]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpe
>   ner.java:108)
>       [apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:284)
>       [apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:2
>   20)
>       [apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:176)
>       [apply]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:157)
>       [apply]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:89)
>       [apply] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       [apply]     at com.android.dx.cf.code.ConcreteMethod.(ConcreteMethod.j
>   ava:84)
>       [apply]     at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslato
>   r.java:243)
>       [apply]     ... 14 more
>       [apply] ...while processing  ()V
>       [apply] ...while processing com/google/android/apps/analytics/AnalyticsRecei
>   ver.class
>       [apply]
>       [apply] 1 error; aborting
>
> BUILD FAILED K:\build.xml:343: The
>   following error occurred while
>   executing this line: K:\build.xml:205:
>   apply returned: 1

I believe it has something to do with using the AnalyticsReceiver.jar lib. But I know my code works as I have successfully compiled it with Eclipse

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by removing `libGoogleAnalytics-interface.jar` from the Libs folder